# How to sort list like this?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list like this:

```
li = [
  {
    'name': 'Lee',
    'age': 22
  },
  {
    'name': 'Mike',
    'age': 34
  },
  {
    'name': 'John',
    'age': 23
  }
]
```

I want sort the list with `sorted` method, and sort by the the `age` key

How to achieve it?

Comment: It just so happens that `sorted` will do this implicitly if you let it use its defaults.

Comment: @kojiro: we probably shouldn't rely on that.  See [this section](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#not-in) of the Python 2.7 docs; in Python 3 the comparison fails with a TypeError.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [key function](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#key-functions):

```
li_sorted = sorted(li, key=lambda x: x['age'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The Python3 equivalent of what @kojiro suggests is this

```
>>> sorted(li, key=lambda x:sorted(x.items()))
[{'age': 22, 'name': 'Lee'}, {'age': 23, 'name': 'John'}, {'age': 34, 'name': 'Mike'}]
```

Clearly this is less efficient than

```
>>> sorted(li, key=lambda x:x['age'])
[{'age': 22, 'name': 'Lee'}, {'age': 23, 'name': 'John'}, {'age': 34, 'name': 'Mike'}]
```

anyway. There is also the advantage that it doesn't rely on the fact that `'age' < 'name'`

Here's how to write the same thing using `itemgetter`

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(li, key=itemgetter('age'))
[{'age': 22, 'name': 'Lee'}, {'age': 23, 'name': 'John'}, {'age': 34, 'name': 'Mike'}]
```